# Horizontally "reveal" text in a container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like a transition like this

```
#my-div {
  width: 20px;
  transition: width 1s ease;
}

#my-div:hover {
  width: 100%
}
```

Inside my div will be an icon that sits inside the 20px. When you mouse over the icon the width will expand to it's parent's container. Here's where I'm getting tripped up. I want the text "Auto Refresh" to be centered at the 100% width **at all times**. So when the container is at 20px then "Auto Refresh" text will be hidden because it's too far over (i.e it won't fit inside the 20px width). When you hover over the icon the width will expand revealing the hidden "Auto Refresh" text.

I've tried using `overflow: no-wrap` and `overflow: hidden` but hidden seems to do nothing. I'm wondering if this is even possible in CSS or if I need to use multiple layers and trigger animations on those layers with javascript. Here is the effect I'm going for.

[image]

In the absolute center of the orange div should be "Auto Refresh". I hope the gif conveys my goal well. The important part is that the text is hidden before mouse over and as the orange background slides over it slowly reveals the text as though it was always there, but was just hidden before.

Do I need multiple layers and trigger animations via javascript to accomplish this? Or is this doable in pure CSS?

Relevant HTML (Please excuse the inline style. I'm fiddling with dev tools)

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-12 region-div us-region-div">
<div class="inner border-grey-light">
    <div id="us-datasource" class="crossfade data-source-blizzard-api">
        <img class="bottom" src="assets/data-source-blizzard-api-30x30.png" title="Price data from Battle.net Web API" alt="Price data from Battle.net Web API">
        <img class="top" src="assets/data_source_wow_30x30.png" title="Price data from in-game" alt="Price data from in-game">
    </div>
    <a href="US"><h3 class="region-title">US</h3></a>
    <p class="money-text"><span id="us-money-text" class="odometer">175,673</span><img src="assets/gold-transparent-compressed.png" class="gold"></p>
    <div class="price-trend">
        <span class="money-text-small">
            <span id="us-arrow" class="crossfade down-arrow arrow">
                <img class="bottom" src="assets/downarrow-resized.png">
                <img class="top" src="assets/uparrow-resized.png">
            </span>
            <span id="us-money-text-small" class="odometer">-1,206</span>
            <img src="assets/gold-transparent-compressed.png" class="gold-small">
        </span>
    </div>
    <p id="us-last-change-text" class="last-change">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="us-datetime" class="region-date">&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="refresh-container">
        <div id="patreon">
            <i class="fab fa-patreon" style="
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.25rem;
            top: 12px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 12px;
            "></i>
        </div>
        <a href=""><p id="us-new-price" class="lead new-price show-price"><i id="us-price-refresh-icon" class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i> New Price!</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show also the relevant HTML.

Comment: I don't see the text *Auto Refresh* on the gif, but try using `translateX, opacity` to manipulate the element whose text *Auto Refresh*

Comment: I'd prefer not to use opacity as a means to reveal. I want to see the text immediately as the orange background slides across.

Comment: Can you provide your code in snippet?

Comment: @david2278 Please provide css also. So i can modify into your code as well.

Comment: @RevtiShah Frankly my code is a mess and I have been trying to get my css into codepen, but all my fonts are localhost and it's just not working. I think clip-path may be the answer. Thank you so much for your willingness to help Revti!

Comment: @david2278 Hope this link will help you.   https://jsfiddle.net/9yzLu6o8/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clip-path` to simulate the illusion of the text being revealed when the rectangular `div` container expands. Pure CSS, here are the relevant HTML and CSS you can apply to your code:

```css
#my-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  
  /* Relevant starting here */
  width: 400px;
  transition: clip-path 1s ease;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 20% 0%, 20% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

#my-div:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id = "my-div">This is a test div</div>
```

Comment: @david2278 Clip-path basically cuts the shape of anything to anything you want (specified with your CSS code) while preserving its height and width. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path. Please do accept the answer if it answers your question.